# Creating a share button which combines the count from all social media sites (like the BBC)

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-like, media

I like the way BBC news articles have one share button with a counter that displays a total for all the various social media sites combined.  When you click on the button it pops up a breakdown of the totals for each site individually and allows you to add yourself if you wish.

Does anyone know how this was done or if there is a tutorial for creating something similar as I am struggling to track anything down.

Example page: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-13757380

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example I am currently working on: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/qGDL7/18/